How do I include spaces in a player's name in my scoreboard objectives?
My Minecraft Java Edition version is 1.21.4.
I'm running the command
/scoreboard players add "Players Alive:" scoreboard 5.
However, the game gives me the following error:

Expected whitespace to end one argument, but found trailing data

I found a question that asks about this but it's very old and predates the 1.21.1 syntax changes. Any workaround that doesn't involve mods or datapacks?
